# How to automatically control routing table of router outside?

Tags: linux, networking, router

Currently: I am developing a system called Dataplane which contains 10 blade servers, each assigned an IP address. These 10 servers are connected to a L3 switch. I configure static routing on this switch so that the packet coming is routed to the right server. Because my system need high speed requirement, I have to store data directly in RAM instead of a database. Each blade serves some packets with certain destination IP address.

Problem: I would like to change routing table on the L3 switch automatically depending on the business on my system. The idea firstly comes to my mind is to enable OSPF on the L3 switch and to implement OSPF on the 10 servers (Use open source FFRouting).

So, I would like to consult experts for advice. Could you give me some recommendations about the solution? What is the most feasible solution and what need to be noted when implementing it?

Thank you

Comment: Why wouldn't you use a load balancer instead? Most likely you don't want to reroute packets, but connections.

Comment: @EugenRieck Thankyou, that's a good question. The problem derived from that my system is kind of Dataplane (high speed requirement), every data is directly stored on RAM, i couldn't use a concentrated database. So, packets coming must be routed to the right blade to be served (based on destination IP address). If it were routed to the wrong blade, that blade could not serve because the blade do not have information about that packet

Comment: So a load balancer fits your profile even better! It can decide on a connection basis, which blade to hit.

Comment: @EugenRieck If i use a load balancer, i am afraid the bottle neck is at that device. I do not know much about load balancer. Is it a specialized hardware? And how to reroute packets on load balancer automatically depending on business on blade servers?